# How to get index within `forEach` iterations in Immutable

Tags: javascript, object, immutable.js

Within native javascript `Array.forEach` callback function, we have arguments as: `currentValue[, index[, array]]`.

In [Immutable.js forEach](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/forEach), I cannot seem to get the index value. I think it used to follow the pattern of `Array.forEach`, however, they have changed it.

My question is: how does one get `index` within each iteration of `forEach`. Are we to manually increment an external (outside the function) varible to store a value?

example code:

```
const anObj = Map({
 a : "a",
 b : "b"
});
let i;
// immutable.js way
anObj.forEach((v, k, collection ) => {
 // body of func
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `for` loop? `for(let i = 0; i < anObj.length; i++){...}`. Also, Map is an existing class in HTML5, are you sure you want to keep using something that overwrites native methods?

Comment: @BRO_THOM This is an immutable Map obj.

Answer (score 2):

`var index = anObj.indexOf(v);`

Should return you the index of your value given value.
Might be inefficient, compared to an incremental variable.

Comment: Good answer, definitely an option, & in my opinion a cleaner one too.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/586

Unfortunately, it appears that the dev team decided to deviate from the native Javascript signature as per the above link. So, in essense the recommended approach, as per LeeByron's comment is:

```
var index = 0;
myOrderedMap.forEach(function (item) {
  // do what you need to do with item and index
  index += 1;
});
```